# C - read() and write()

Tags: c

I was working on my class with read() and write() functions and i was trying to a function that writes what it reads and something more in front that i give as an argument.

For example i want to give 10 as an argument of my program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char buf[512];
while(read(0,buf,sizeof(buf)) > 0){
    strcat(buf,argv[1]);
    write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
}

return 0;
}
```

this way if i go to the terminal and do $ ./ex 10
when i write something it should paste what i wrote and "10" in front

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `read` and `write`? They aren't really the right functions to use for this. You probably want `fgets` and `printf`

Comment: How many bytes did `read()` actually read?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: `read()` doesn't add null byte termination (`\0`) but `strcat()` expects a null terminated string.

Comment: @Kevin *Have you looked at the documentation for read and write? They aren't really the right functions to use for this. You probably want `fgets` and `printf`*  `read()` and `write()` aren't the wrong functions, either.  Because `fgets()` is implemented with `read()` and `printf()` is implemented with `write()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't mean to say that you can't do it with `read` and `write`. But higher level functions like `fgets` and `printf` are more suitable.

Comment: Think more about your problem requirement. It is either ambiguous or wrong. What exactly *"it should paste what i wrote and "10" in front"* means? What should happen with an empty input, with several lines? With some redirection? How many bytes do you believe the `read` function is getting?

Comment: @Kevin, in a general sense, yes, higher-level functions relieve you of handling some of the details that the OP is missing.  But they aren't really an option when you have an exercise whose express purpose is to get you to practice using the low-level functions.

Comment: I recommend spending several days reading [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use read() and write() you should learn how those syscall work.

```
read(0,buf,sizeof(buf)
```

In this case, read() will write from the std input, up to 512 characters on your buffer.
The problem is read() doesn't put the '\0' at the end of your buffer.
You have several ways to do that.
One is to use bzero() function, like that :

```
bzero(buf, siezof(buf);
```

**You can also put the char '\0' manually, in your array.**
The other problem is your strcat();
If the user input is more than 512 char, you will overflow your buffer, be careful with that.

The following code should be a good start to find out what you need to do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char buf[512];

  bzero(buf, 512);
  while(read(0,buf,sizeof(buf)) > 0){
    strcat(buf,argv[1]);
    write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
    bzero(buf, 512);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: strlen(buf) is going to fail too. Needs to be sizeof(buf)